# How to add class with delay on elements that are in viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, viewport

The idea is to make script that shows elements only if they are in viewport and with delays between adding the classes. Now when yous scroll and STOP its fine, but when you scroll further script works as it goes back again from the very beginning and adds opacity back again to all elements. But I need it to be applied this only to the next invisible element. How to do this?

```js
    $('.viewport').scroll( function(){
       $('.element').each( function(i, e){
          var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(),
              bottom_of_window = $('.viewport').scrollTop() + $('.viewport').height();
              if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){ 
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).css('opacity', '1');
                }, i * 1000);
                                   
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background: #95B8D1;
  font-family: "Pt Sans", sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  min-height: 100vh
}
.viewport {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: #747474;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.element {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're checking all elements once again on each `scroll` event:

```
  $('.viewport').scroll( function(){
    $('.element').each( function(i, e){
```

why not to add specific class to the elements that are already marked and start with next one.
So initally yo'll have html class like this

```
<div class="element transparent">Lo...</div>
```

and then int your Javascript:

```
    $('.viewport').scroll( function(){
//mind additional class here
       $('.element.transparent').each( function(i, e){
          var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(),
              bottom_of_window = $('.viewport').scrollTop() + $('.viewport').height();
              if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){ 
//remove from filter in next run
$(this).removeClass('transparent');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).css('opacity', '1');
                }, i * 1000);

            }

        }); 

    });
```